# F#: Composing sprintf with a string -> unit function to allow formatting

Tags: f#, printf

There's information out there on how to do [custom processing on a format and its parts](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/07/abusing-printfformat-in-f.html). I want to do something a bit simpler, specifically, I want to do something to the effect of:

```
let writelog : string -> unit = ... // write the string to the log

let writelogf = sprintf >> writelog // write a formatted string to the log
```

I'm not too surprised that the compiler gets confused by this, but is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://github.com/robertpi/log4f. It's a thin wrapper round log4net to allow you to write: logger.Info "Hello %s" "world"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way to define your own function that takes a formatting string like `printf` is to use `Printf.kprintf` function. The first argument of `kprintf` is a function that is used to display the resulting string after formatting (so you can pass it your `writelog` function):

```
let writelog (s:string) = printfn "LOG: %s" s
let writelogf fmt = Printf.kprintf writelog fmt
```

The `fmt` parameter that is passed as a second argument is the special format string. This works better than *jpalmer*'s solution, because if you specify some additional arguments, they will be directly passed to `kprintf` (so the number of arguments can depend on the formatting string).

You can write:

```
> writelogf "Hello";;
LOG: Hello

> writelogf "Hello %d" 42;;
LOG: Hello 42
```

Comment: Hah, that's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
> let writelog = fun (s:string) -> printfn "%s" s;;

val writelog : string -> unit

> let writelogf arg = sprintf arg >> writelog;;

val writelogf : Printf.StringFormat<('a -> string)> -> ('a -> unit)

> writelogf "hello %s" "world";;
hello world
val it : unit = ()
>
```

(session is from FSI)

key is in the extra argument to writelogf

Comment: @ankur - this is the same problem as doing let t = "hi"; printf t - the compiler doesn't coerce the string literal to the format string type